# VBA - Custom Function to close work book - not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a simple function (in a module FileIO) which would take an instance of a work book, and just close it. This function is invoked from another module Business.
Below is the code snippet.

```
Public Function CloseExcelFile(wkBook As Workbook)
    If (wkBook Is Not Nothing) Then
        wkBook.Save
        wkBook.Close
    End If
End Function
```

I invoke this method by using the command `FileIO.CloseExcelFile(catWorkBook)`. Variable `catWorkBook` is the object reference to the workbook I created (in a step before).

When ever I try too invoke the custom function, I am getting the error

> object does not support this method or property

The below command closes the work book with no errors.

```
catWorkBook.Close
```

But the same does not happen when I use the custom function. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Change `Function` to `Sub`

Comment: You created the variable catWorkbook. So, you should know it exists and is open, right? Why not just use catWorkbook.close SaveChanges:=True instead of a function/sub at all.

Comment: I was just trying to make the whole thing a bit modular, and make all File IO operations to be bundled into one module (FileIO). I may have to fall back to your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have your `Not` in the wrong place. Try it like this:

```
Public Function CloseExcelFile(wkBook As Workbook)
    If Not wkBook Is Nothing Then
        wkBook.Save
        wkBook.Close
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Did not seem to work. I kept the file closing logic in the business module itself. But just wrote a simple function
`Sub CloseExcelFile()`

Now, the program is working without errors. The work book I created is getting closed and this method CloseExcelFile() is also getting called. I get the MsgBox message displayed. 

I changed the sub routine to take Workbook as a parameter.
`Sub CloseExcelFile(newWkBook As Workbook)`

Updated the invoking code as 
`FileIO.CloseExcelFile (catWorkbook)`
Started getting the error message; "Object does'nt support this property or method".

Answer (score 2):

As braX pointed out, your `Not` isn't in the right place.

You also don't need a `Function` here. Change it to a `Sub`. In fact, you barely need the Sub when you reduce it to one line like this:

```
Public Sub CloseExcelFile(wkBook As Workbook)
    If Not wkBook Is Nothing Then wkBook.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to the **INCORRECT** way I was invoking a sub routine. I invoked the sub routine as:-

```
FileIO.CloseExcelFile(catWorkBook)
```

The **CORRECT** way to invoke a function would have been.

```
FileIO.CloseExcelFile catWorkBook
```